# How to set the right RCurl options to download from NSE website

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

I am trying to download files from the NSE India website (nseindia.com). The problem is that webmaster does not like scraping programs downloading files or reading pages from the website. They have a user agent based restriction it seems.

The file I am trying to download is http://www.nseindia.com/archives/equities/bhavcopy/pr/PR280815.zip

I am able to download this from the linux shell using

```
curl -v -A "Mozilla" http://www.nseindia.com/archives/equities/bhavcopy/pr/PR280815.zip
```

The output is this

> About to connect() to www.nseindia.com port 80 (#0)
>   *   Trying 115.112.4.12...   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
>   --:--:--     0connected
>
> > GET /archives/equities/bhavcopy/pr/PR280815.zip HTTP/1.1
> >     User-Agent: Mozilla
> >     Host: www.nseindia.com
> >     Accept: */*
> >     < HTTP/1.1 200 OK < Server: Oracle-iPlanet-Web-Server/7.0 < Content-Length: 374691 < X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN < Last-Modified:
> >     Fri, 28 Aug 2015 12:20:02 GMT < ETag: "5b7a3-55e051f2" <
> >     Accept-Ranges: bytes < Content-Type: application/zip < Date: Sat, 29
> >     Aug 2015 17:56:05 GMT < Connection: keep-alive < { [data not shown] PK
> >     5  365k    5 19977    0     0  34013      0  0:00:11 --:--:--  0:00:11
> >     56592

This allows me to the download the file.

The code I am using in R Curl is this

```
  library("RCurl")

  jurl <- "http://www.nseindia.com/archives/equities/bhavcopy/pr/PR280815.zip"
  juseragent <- "Mozilla"
  myOpts = curlOptions(verbose = TRUE, header = TRUE, useragent = juseragent)
  jfile <- getURL(jurl,.opts=myOpts)
```

This, too, does not work.

I have also unsuccessfully tried using download.file from the *base* library with the user agent changed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not "doesn't like" it's "legally prohibits":http://www.nseindia.com/global/content/termsofuse.htm. Just because you _can_ do something in R doesn't mean you _should_.

Comment: Refer the `nser` package. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nser/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your problem is not setting the user agent, but downloading binary data. This works:

```
jfile <- getURLContent(jurl, .opts=myOpts, binary=TRUE)
```

Here is a (more) complete example using `httr` instead of `RCurl`.

```
library(httr)
url <- "http://www.nseindia.com/archives/equities/bhavcopy/pr/PR280815.zip"
response <- GET(url, user_agent("Mozilla"))
response$status                                          # 200 OK
# [1] 200
tf <- tempfile()
writeBin(content(response, "raw"), tf)                   # write response content (the zip file) to a temporary file
files <- unzip(tf, exdir=tempdir())                      # unzips to system temp directory and returns a vector of file names
df.lst <- lapply(files[grepl("\\.csv$",files)],read.csv) # convert .csv files to list of data.frames
head(df.lst[[2]])
#      SYMBOL SERIES                  SECURITY HIGH.LOW INDEX.FLAG
# 1 AGRODUTCH     EQ AGRO DUTCH INDUSTRIES LTD        H         NA
# 2    ALLSEC     EQ   ALLSEC TECHNOLOGIES LTD        H         NA
# 3      ALPA     BE     ALPA LABORATORIES LTD        H         NA
# 4      AMTL     EQ     ADV METERING TECH LTD        H         NA
# 5  ANIKINDS     BE       ANIK INDUSTRIES LTD        H         NA
# 6   ARSHIYA     EQ           ARSHIYA LIMITED        H         NA
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(curl) # this is not RCurl, you need to download curl
```

to download file in the working directory

```
curl_download("http://www.nseindia.com/archives/equities/bhavcopy/pr/PR280815.zip","tt.zip",handle = new_handle("useragent" = "my_user_agent"))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering metrics. Unfortunately curl does not seem to be working with my version of R.

Comment: Which version are you using? I am using `0.9.2`